# remote database access on remote access disabled server

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysql-workbench, remote-access

I need a help about remote access.

I want to remote access to database on the web hosting server, but this feature is disabled, also for statik IP.

I was wondering that if it is possible to put a php script on hosting and connect local database manager (like intelijidea datagrip, mysql workbench or whichever is possible) via the link.

I don't know if it is possible or not. Also, can you let me know if there is another way to make true this.

If you can help me, it will be so good for me.

Thank you

Edit: There is a option on intelij "New Data Source from Url" you can see ss from below link, can it help me ?

SS: http://prnt.sc/b53z12

Comment: Software like IntelliJ IDEA, MySQL Workbench and such make use of TCP connections to setup a connection to the database, they don't use a PHP script. As such, there is no way to connect with this software as long as your host is not allowing you to do so. But you should be able to setup something like phpMyAdmin on the remote server and open that in your browser locally to adjust things.

Comment: something like phpMyAdmin installed on the server should help you. Also, ask your hosting company, they might allow you some sort of ssh access (maybe even jailed), using ssh you should be able to access your local db.

Comment: Thank you for answwer, but phpmyadmin alredy there is. I edited my question and added and ss can you check and answer please.

Comment: Do local database managers use ssh ? If so, can you share an example of document ?